# Sending gif image to the messaging app

Tags: android, gif, mms

I want to send gif using MMS image.I wrote the code it is working on Android 6 version but below it is not working messaging app getting a crash.

Here is my code.

```
     mGifFile = getFileForResource(ImageKeyboard.this, imageId[position], imagesDir, "image_new.gif" );
     Uri newFile =   FileProvider.getUriForFile(ImageKeyboard.this, AUTHORITY, mGifFile);


                String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(ImageKeyboard.this); //Need to change the build to API 19
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
                   intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi how are you");
                   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, newFile);
                   intent.setType("image/gif");
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   ImageKeyboard.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you checked your log? Can you provide that please

Comment: what is the error on crashing in crash log

Comment: I did n't get any log. it displays the message Unfortunately messaging has Stoped.@H.Brooks

Comment: On your console(in the program that you are using) not on your device..

Answer (score 0):

You can get default sms package name in API <19 by creating a method like this:

```
public static final String getDefaultSmsPackage(Context context){
    String defApp = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "sms_default_application");
    PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    Intent iIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(defApp);
    ResolveInfo mInfo = pm.resolveActivity(iIntent,0);
    return mInfo.activityInfo.packageName; 
}
```

This code is equivalent to your

```
Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(...)
```